# lumen doesn't use the right database directory on migration

Tags: laravel, lumen

in Lumen when i try to create a database migration the artisan try to store the migration file on my-project/database folder which causes  an error because the migration folder in Lumen located under my-project/model/migration. so why artisan doesn't use the Lumen migration folder.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated that `lumen` tries to store the migrations inside the `database/migrations` and it is the intended behaviour and is by the design.

If you want the proof it is here:

> https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#migrations

**It has already stated that it uses laravel type of migration behaviour.**

So, you must try to maintain the structure if you want to create and run migration using default standard, which would be great if in near future you want to migrate to laravel from lumen.

Also you have stated that lumen's migration is inside `model`. It was never there by the design. You might have changed the folder structure of the migrations.

Want the proof :

> https://github.com/laravel/lumen/tree/master/database/migrations
>
> https://github.com/laravel/lumen/tree/5.0/database/migrations
>
> https://github.com/laravel/lumen/tree/5.2/database/migrations
>
> https://github.com/laravel/lumen/tree/5.3/database/migrations

Hope it clears your confusions.